# How to put a static class member in a namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, static-members

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>

class api
{
private:
    void psParser ()
    {
        std::stringstream psOutput;
        psOutput << "ps --no-headers -f -p " << getpid() << " > .txt";

        system (psOutput.str().c_str());

        std::stringstream processInfo;
        processInfo << ":"__FILE__ << ":" << __DATE__ << ":" << __TIME__ << ":";
    }

public:
    static std::stringstream message;
};

namespace sstreamss
{
    std :: stringstream api :: message;
};

int main ()
{
    api::message << "zxzx";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

`error: definition of ‘api::message’ is not in namespace enclosing ‘api’`

I want that `static std::stringstream message` should be accessible at a global scope, so I want this under a namespace.

What's the way out?

Comment: Put the whole class `api` in the namespace?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Is that **necessary**? Can't a member be in a namespace?

Comment: What you are doing is changing the scope of the member, and that is not allowed.

Comment: Are you sure you want it to be "static"?

Comment: @SChepurin actually, I want it to work like `std::cout`. std is a namespace. My variable is a class memeber. I don't want people to start creating objects for accessing it.

Comment: @Anisha Kaul - So, either use namespace consistently wrapping every class in own namespace (as  juanchopanza suggested) or remove it altogether.

Comment: The crucial difference is that `cout` is a plain old global variable in the `std` namespace, and you have a *class* member, which you can only access using the `api::` scope anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you want to have the *same* instance of `api::message` accessible across all translation units that have access to `api`. Unlike plain, non-class `static` data, which have internal linkage, `static` class members have external linkage. This means the same instance is seen everywhere. So you do not have to play any games with namespaces. A namespace wouldn't change anything here, but it would have to enclose the whole `api` class anyway.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to use singleton design pattern. Define a public static accessor function to access the instance.

```
class api
{
 private:
 static bool instanceFlag;
 static api* inst;
 ....
  ....
 public:
 static api* getInstance();
 inline void display(std::string msg)
 { 
       std::cout<<msg;
 }
};
bool api::instanceFlag = false;
api* api::inst = NULL;

api* api::getInstance()
{
 if(! instanceFlag)
 {
    inst = new api();
    instanceFlag = true;
    return inst;
 }
 else
 {
    return inst;
 }
}
int main()
{
  // Access the static instance. Same instance available everywhere
  api::getInstance()->display("zxzx");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared class `api` in global namespace you can't define  member in another namespace.
What you need to do is to define `api::message` in a cpp file

api.h

```
class api
{
private:
    void psParser ()
    {
        std::stringstream psOutput;
        psOutput << "ps --no-headers -f -p " << getpid() << " > .txt";

        system (psOutput.str().c_str());

        std::stringstream processInfo;
        processInfo << ":"__FILE__ << ":" << __DATE__ << ":" << __TIME__ << ":";
    }

public:
    static std::stringstream message;
};
```

api.cpp

```
std::stringstream api::message;
```

main.cpp

```
#include "api.h"

int main ()
{
    api::message << "zxzx";

    return 0;
}
```

But it's not the best practice to make `std::stringstream` static, you may want to make it a local variable if you could.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't compile because you're trying to put `api::message` into a different namespace from `api` itself.

> I want that `static std::stringstream message` should be accessible at a global scope

If you want it accessible at the global scope, don't put it in a namespace.

Comment: `If you want it accessible at the global scope, don't put it in a namespace.` By global I mean in different cpp files.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: How do you expect `namespace sstreamss` to help with that?

Comment: @AnishaKaul `std::cout` would also work as `cout` without any namespaces. The namespace really doesn't come into it.

Comment: @juanchopanza why? don't we have to use `using namespace std;` for cout?

Comment: @AnishaKaul what I mean is that the whole standard library could have been implemented without the `std` namespace, in which case the use of `cout` would be exactly the same as the use of `std::cout` in the real standard library.

Comment: @juanchopanza I know that, but namespace is used to prevent name clashes, so that's why I want it. I actually want this member to be accessed by all classes/functions without having to create multiple objects of the class - hence static.

Comment: @AnishaKaul there is nothing in your question to suggest you want to avoid name clashes. If you really want to avoid name clashes, then put `api` in a namespace.

Comment: @juanchopanza I have done it now. I thought using namespace would indicate that I want to avoid name clashes. Anyway, is using static a good idea?